# Convert Flagged Posts Into Close Reasons

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

This may not be the best title but maybe my picture will explain it better.

[image]

In the above image, it shows "exact duplicate ... URL".

I now understand how this has been happening after reading the comments to my question at this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92623/auto-generate-the-possible-duplicate-comment-when-question-is-flagged-as-a-dupl).

As you can see, the message was not voted to close but rather was flagged by a lower rep user who does not have the ability to vote to close.

If I want to use that as the close reason, I have to right click, copy the link, then click close question, paste the link, tab out to remove focus and cause the Vote to Close button to become un-grayed out, and then click Vote to Close.

**EDIT:
This also applies to questions flagged as Off Topic.**

Is there a reason for this long process? Why not just convert the flag into a close reason - at least in 10K tools?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the "tab out to remove focus and cause the Vote to Close button to become un-grayed out" part?

Comment: @agf: After pasting the link, you have to tab out so it removes focus from the textfield in order to click the vote to close button. It has to load the preview.

Comment: When you vote to close a question as a duplicate, don't you get a list of what other users chose?

Comment: @lunboks but no one chose that duplicate yet as a close reason -- just as a flag reason -- so it doesn't show up.

Comment: 0A0D - I've never had to do that. It just loads the preview after I paste the link.

Comment: @agf: Never had for me.

Comment: Might want to report that as a bug. What browser / OS? Works for me on Win7 / FF7Beta

Comment: I would rather like to allow users who can vote to close to see if a question has been already flagged to be closed.

Comment: @agf: Win XP, FF6

Comment: @kiamlaluno Why not both? Though that is one of the benefits of 10k rep rather than 3k or whatever...

Comment: On a related note, flags with close reasons from 3k+ users are already automatically converted to close votes.

Comment: @Anna: Yep, so it seems that we have a disconnect. I don't know how easily it can be implemented since you would be essentially giving low-rep users the ability to close albeit via an indirect 10K+ user.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this has been implemented at some point.

If you open the close vote dialog on a question with dupe flags on it, the flagger's suggestion will appear in the "other users chose these questions as the best duplicate" section — even if no actual close votes were cast yet.