# Recommending users to flag duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I see a lot of times comments to a question saying that it's a duplicate.

If you notice that's the case, why not flag the question instead of, or in addition to, making the comment? If nobody flags it, it will be kept as a duplicate. And I've seen a lot of duplicates still open.

Can you think of a user-friendly way to recommend users to flag a duplicate question?

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92623/auto-generate-the-possible-duplicate-comment-when-question-is-flagged-as-a-dup

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comment you see is inserted automatically when someone vote to close the question as duplicate.

However, it requires five votes to really close the question, so many times the question simply won't get enough close votes.

With enough reputation you can see the pending close votes.

Comment: That includes my own vote? Or I can only see other people's vote?

Comment: Only the first vote will add such comment, if it's not linked already in previous (non automatic) comment. If the comment comes from user with less than 3K reputation it means manual comment and not close vote.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - for users less than 3K it can still be automatic through the flag as duplicates dialog I think.

Comment: @awoodland thanks, wasn't aware of that!

Comment: @awoodland No, that doesn't happen.