# Reason for adding comment "possible duplicate of ..."

Tags: support, comments, flags, duplicate-questions

If anyone finds a post as dupe and flagged it means, we are showing the message

> possible duplicate of ...

as a comment of that flagged user.

What is the reason for that?

I think it is a message to the OP to alter the post to stand unique(Now, on-hold process do the same thing).

So, it is enough to show the comment to the OP itself. But, it is visible to everyone. So, other than this what is the genuine reason for posting a comment?

For me it's a great thing that I can easily flag that post without searching for the dupes of that post in the site and can easily increase the number of helpful flags.

Comment: You may find some reasons here: [Auto-generate the “possible duplicate” comment when question is flagged as a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92623/auto-generate-the-possible-duplicate-comment-when-question-is-flagged-as-a-dup).

Comment: @AzizShaikh, sorry I can't find, can u get an answer from there?

Comment: It may not be exactly what you are looking for but I found two possible reasons for posting such a comment: 1) "it would allow others (especially those with enough rep to vote to close) to avoid having to hunt down the link". 2) "This would also allow the community to close questions before the moderators got around to assessing the flags, taking some of the load off them".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having possible duplicates linked on a question points people to existing possible answers for the problem. The OP, as well as anybody else looking for a answer to the question, gets a pointer to a different question where they might find that answer, or at least related information that could help.

Having this relevant information linked helps everybody to understand and solve the problem at hand. The OP, other people searching for an answer and finding the question via google, people browsing SO and being curious about the question, and even people trying to answer the question should be happy to be linked to a related question where the answer might already be found.

This applies both to the time span after somebody voted to close and before the question really got closed, as well as to cases where the question doesn't end up getting closed as a duplicate at all.