# Auto-generated possible duplicate comment should not be removed after closure

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

When a user votes to close a question as a duplicate an [automatically generated comment is added to the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92623/auto-generate-the-possible-duplicate-comment-when-question-is-flagged-as-a-dup).

As soon as the question is closed, this comment is removed. (I am not sure what happens with the comment if the question is reopened or if the questions is never closed and the close votes are lost by "aging" or votes in the close-votes review queue. But I suppose that it is removed in these cases too.)

I think that this comment should be left there:

- Some users might react to that comment explaining why, in their opinion, the question is not a duplicate. By removal of the comment the context of this discussion is lost.
- If the question is reopened, it might be useful to keep the comment, so that the question is listed among linked questions. (Even if the choice as a duplicate was incorrect, it is probably still related to the other questions.)
- This would also help to keep the track of several closures of the same question (if it has been reopened).

(For the reasons I have mentioned above I usually post a link in a comment before casting vote to close; so that I know that comment with the link is not removed.)

Comment: The `@`-reply will also work for any of the users who voted to close. All closu events are recorded in the revisions list. I think the linked questions will still show it, although not sure about this one.

Comment: Posting a link in a comment is not, necessarily, enough :-(.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards That's not really a duplicate. It's a sub-set of the feature requested here.

Comment: Agree with @Duncan, voting to reopen. (Saw that other question while looking for dupe)

Comment: Illustrating the problem in question, ben's comment linked to this question: [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified). But that comment is now deleted.