# Upvoting the "possible duplicate" comment counts as flag as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, comments, duplicate-questions

If someone already flagged a question as duplicate and there is already the **auto-generated "possible duplicate" comment** visible, like for example:

> possible duplicate of How to compare Strings in Java

Is upvoting this duplicate-comment considered as a **flag-as-duplicate** or should I also flag the question?

For the case the upvote of the dupl-comment is not considered as a flag-as-duplicate: Maybe it should? It would be *more convenient* than clicking through the flagging menus. Also I think an upvote of the dupl-comment is a pretty *clear expression* already that the user agrees that it is a duplicate.

see also the related question here: [Auto-generate the "possible duplicate" comment when question is flagged as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92623/auto-generate-the-possible-duplicate-comment-when-question-is-flagged-as-a-dup)

Comment: I will upvote the duplicate comment, if it is helpful.   E.g. it helps to answer the question.     I am NOT saying by the upvote that it provides an answer to the complete question.   E.g I may upvote the comment even if I don't think it is a true dupicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the comment was generated by a flag (or vote) to close, adding another flag of the same kind would be without a consequence anyway. Close **votes** have a cumulative effect, flags do not.

You can still upvote if you feel the duplicate is spot on; though this is not of much consequence either.

Comment: So I would anyway waste my time to flag a question as duplicate that has been already flagged as dupl before?

Comment: @donfuxx Basically yes. Okay, there is *one* consequence: your flag will be marked as helpful (automatically) if the reviewers agree with it; and this will improve your flagging record, perhaps increasing the number of flags you can cast per day in the future. Whether or not that's worth your time, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Not any more as flags now timeout after 14 days.

Answer (score 1):

No, upvoting a comment is not flagging.

And it should not be. We don't want people not knowing that flag post implicitly by upvoting comments. Let's keep upvoting and flagging seperate to avoid a mess. We already have enough invalid flags in the queue.

If you don't have the time to make 3 click to flag a post then you should not do it at all since you might act too fast anyway.

Comment: I see the point that it is not wanted that users trigger a flag without knowing it. But maybe this is an exception, because if someone _upvotes_ the dupl-comment he also _agrees_ to the statement that the question is a duplicate? (what else could be the reason for upvoting such comment?)

Comment: @donfuxx,  I will upvote the duplicate comment, if it is helpful. E.g. it helps to answer the question. I am NOT saying by the upvote that it provides an answer to the complete question. E.g I may upvote the comment even if I don't think it is a true dupicate.