# Closed as "Not a Real Question" by Moderator after only Four Minutes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moderators should not close crap, flamebait questions, let the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92508/moderators-should-not-close-crap-flamebait-questions-let-the-community)

The question "[Query LDAP for all computer objects created in the last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391174/c-sharp-query-ldap-for-all-computer-objects-created-in-the-last-24-hours)" was closed by a single moderator after only four minutes. Surely we could have given the OP a little longer to get his question together?

Comment: Reaction times must be getting slower

Comment: He has plenty of time. He can still edit it and flag for reopening. No big deal.

Comment: @random It was really closed after a little less than two minutes. Not too slow.

Comment: @animuson: new users don't always get that they can edit the question. Give a newbie a chance here.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: So post a comment?

Comment: @JohnSaunders " member for 1 year, 3 months". Not really a newbie.

Comment: @animuson: how about instead, we give the new guy a chance to read the comment that was already posted there, and to fix his question, before a moderator-close. If it had been a community close (five votes), then I wouldn't have raised this issue.

Comment: @DanielFischer: in terms of his participation in the community, he's a newbie: this is only his fourth question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: The problem is then you open the potential for *other* "newbies" to go ahead and post crap answers that don't help anyone because the question is too vague or incomplete. I'd rather it be closed until it's fixed, then users are restricted to the comments, where they should be.

Comment: @animuson: I didn't say the question should not have been closed. I said it should not have been closed by a single moderator vote after two minutes. It gives the OP no time to correct the question before it's closed.

Comment: @animuson: anybody who thinks I'm in favor of keeping crap questions around "doesn't know me very well".

Comment: @aminuson. What should be in the comment? Is something like `Please improve your question  by editing your question to <insert relevant text> and then flag your question requesting to reopen?` correct?

Comment: If he's a newbie how does he know that diamond equates to moderator? Most newbies assume that anyone who can vote is a moderator in my experience.

Comment: @awoodland: I have made no statement about whether or not the OP knows what the diamond means. _I_ am the one who knows that it was a single moderator vote. My problem is that a single vote within two minutes closed the question. If _five_ votes within two minutes had closed the question, then I would have had little problem with it.

Comment: If there's no disputing the question closure was valid what difference does it make who closed it, especially when a subtlety like that is going to be lost on the poster?

Comment: The difference is that, if five people had needed to vote on the closure, it would probably have taken much longer to close. The question isn't bad enough that five people would have voted to close that quickly.

Comment: I also deny that this is a duplicate. The linked duplicate refers a question that's _far_ worse than this one. The question I posted about needs little more than to have the OP state what the specific problem is. In fact, the OP has been able to solve the problem, and has presented a solution.

Answer (score 21):

I really don't understand why it matters how long it took. The community votes to close similar questions that quickly all the time. The vast majority of which either get solved in the comments and become too localized or the OP pulls the disappearing act and never actually replies to those comments to improve the question.

If Robert had closed the question after 15 minutes instead of 2, nothing would have been different. It took the OP near 20 minutes to reply to the comment. Sometimes it can take the OP hours or even days to get back and actually check the question again. I don't support bad questions sitting around open for any period of time, even if it's just a few seconds. Single vote or not, if it deserves to be closed it should be closed.

As for giving him a chance, the OP already had a chance. They can take **as long as they want** when writing the question, and this person chose to wing it and throw something out there that wasn't complete. Now it appears he's edited an answer directly into the question.

I agree that newbies can sometimes become confused when their question gets closed, but the comments *are* listed before the close box, so if they didn't bother reading them to find out what they need to do to fix their question (because in most cases there *are* comments), then they obviously don't care.

Comment: +1 for "They can take as long as they want when writing the question" alone

Comment: I have not seen a question like that closed that quickly by five votes. I've seen horrendous questions closed that quickly, but this one isn't as bad as that.

Comment: Also, the comment did not tell the OP what to do. It began the process of engaging the OP in improving the question. However, the question was closed before the author, even with the best intentions in the world, could have taken action to correct the question.

Answer (score 14):

> Surely we could have given the OP a little longer to get his question together?

This is precisely what closure is for.

It gives the asker all the time in the world to get his question together, while preventing the influx of a bunch of answers that will be rendered incorrect or irrelevant as soon as the question is edited. It also allows people to make suggestions in the comments about how the question might be improved, or even for the asker to take the discussion to Meta if he needs additional help.

Once he's gotten the question together, he can flag it for moderator attention to get it re-opened.

Closing a question is not the same thing as deleting it.  Closure doesn't block edits. It's like placing the question temporarily on "hold", pending revisions. If it doesn't get revised within a reasonable amount of time, then yes, it's subject to being removed altogether.

Comment: "All the time in the world"? The question is now about to be deleted, most likely due to the fact that I've drawn attention to it.

Comment: That is a risk you take when you draw attention to things on Meta.

Comment: I'm aware of that. What led you to believe that I was unaware of the risk?

Comment: Related: [I propose changing the term “closed” out for… something else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70061/1438).