# Question missing from the questions list

Tags: support

So, I wanted to drag forth [one of the heaviest downvoted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed) on Meta (for anecdotal purposes only). Since I could not find the question [in the question list sorted by votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=731&sort=votes), I assumed it was deleted.

But after finding it via Google, it turned out it was not deleted...so, are questions with a certain amount of downvotes removed from the list?

Answer (score 1):

Having just cast the 50<sup>th</sup> downvote on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92508/moderators-should-not-close-crap-flamebait-questions-let-the-community) it appears that they disappear at **-50** from the question list.

Comment: Very well, -50 then is...but I still demand that that's a new feature. ;)