# Massively downvoted questions are still missing from the list of questions

Tags: bug, questions, sorting

The [last page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1328&sort=votes) of the list of questions on Meta is currently [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92508/moderators-should-not-close-crap-flamebait-questions-let-the-community) that has a score of -55.  Missing from the bottom of the list are:

- **-84** [Evaluating the risks of allowing teen moderators on the SE network [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network)
- **-90** [“Forced” retirement for top users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142119/forced-retirement-for-top-users)
- **-118** [Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

and who knows how many others.  Those have been around long enough that caching shouldn't be the culprit.

What sounds like the same problem was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) back in December:
[Questions missing from Highest Voted Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115813/questions-missing-from-highest-voted-questions)
reported again in January (with added sorting craziness) and commented as no-repro:
[Glitch when sorting questions by vote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120204/glitch-when-sorting-questions-by-vote-count) (<strike>I can't repro the especially weird sorting that they saw</strike> [Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142458/massively-downvoted-questions-are-still-missing-from-the-list-of-questions#comment403736_142458) found [the magic point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdaiL.png)!)
and then again in June with no developer response:
[Question missing from the questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135074/question-missing-from-the-questions-list)

Since it's <strike>fun to rubberneck</strike> *important to see which ideas the community has already rejected*, can we get this fixed (again)?

Comment: What, you mean there's actually questions with votes somewhere [between 77 and -91](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fdaiL.png)?

Comment: Prepare for those questions to be downvoted even more in 3...2...1

Comment: Took long enough for that teen-mods question to be deleted again.

Comment: I was wondering where those went! I was trying to show someone that "forced retirement" wasn't the lowest voted post, but didn't see the other 2 on your list when searching

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You've really got a chip on your shoulder about that one, huh?  =)

Comment: They do show up on [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?page=726&sort=votes&pagesize=15)

Comment: @jadarnel27: I don't hold any grudges against that guy; he doesn't even deserve it ;) In fact, the whole thing played out pretty hilariously - that post wasn't the last of it. I wish I could show you more :/

Comment: In [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135074/question-missing-from-the-questions-list/135078#135078) it appeared that they are hidden once their score reaches -50 (whether intentional or not)

Comment: Weird, I [see them now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2603&sort=votes).  I was was able to repro this yesterday.  (well, I see all of your examples, anyway.  There's still a gap between -55 and -101, but I'm not sure if any undeleted questions fall into that segment).

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yeah, I'm seeing them in the right place now too.  Maybe a dev will stop by at some point to claim credit.

Comment: I've seen this happen recently, as well, with the licensing announcement question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qop9.png