# Why when I sort questions by votes I don't see this question on the last page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, question-lists, downvoted-questions

There is [the most down voted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly) on SO I found. However, when I sort by votes and go to the [last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=148769&sort=votes) (I choose 50 questions per page), I don't see it. Why?

Comment: Interesting: when explicitly adding votes in the search, it is found (right now on [page 404928](http://stackoverflow.com/search?pagesize=50&page=404928&tab=votes&q=votes%3a-999..99999) when using 50 results per page).

Comment: @Arjan This is how I found this question ))

Comment: Well, this is a bug... related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142458/massively-downvoted-questions-are-still-missing-from-the-list-of-questions) but different since that other report is for Meta. That said, you better post this on MSO, not here.

Comment: I think it nicely fits here, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @Arjan why? It's specific to Stack Overflow. (+1 from me regardless, as it's a weird bug :))

Comment: I'm quite sure the bug (or feature) is in the software that powers all sites, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @Arjan more like in some permanent caching, don't think it's in code. Anyway, let's hope the team will have a look and fix it, no matter where it's posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question has a [Historical Significance lock](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), which

> completely freezes a question and its answers, preventing all further editing, voting, answering, and flagging. It will also **remove it from the usual lists of questions** on the site

It can be found via */search*, but not by browsing the list of */questions* (no matter how the list is sorted).

Comment: Now I'm anGRY with myself for not spotting it earlier!